# Python: Create New Column based on values of other column using len()

Tags: python, pandas, count, series, literals

My dataframe is a pandas dataframe df with many rows & columns.
Now i want to create a new column (series) based on the values of an  object column. e.g.:

df.iloc[0, 'oldcolumn'] Output is 0 should give me **0** in a new column and

df.iloc[1, 'oldcolumn'] Output is 'ab%$.' should give me **5** in the same new column (number of literals incl. space).

in addition, is there a way to avoid loops or own functions?
Thank U

Comment: Can you post what you already tried?

Comment: You can use [`pd.Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html).

Answer (score 0):

To create a new column based on the length of the value in another column, you should do

```py
df['newcol'] = df['oldcol'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)))
```

Although this is a generic way of creating a new column based on data from existing columns, Henry's approach is also a good one.

> In addition, is there a way to avoid loops or own functions?

I recommend you take a look at [How To Make Your Pandas Loop 71803 Times Faster](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['strlen'] = df['oldcolumn'].apply(len)
print(df)
```